# JQuery load with parameters to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use JQuery `.load` to get data from a PHP script file, but for some reason I can not get my parameters in the PHP script.

My load call (I don't really need the alert, but I put it in just to be sure):

```
    $("#m_target").load("mytest.php", { a:"def", b:"1234" }
             ,function(data){alert("Data: " + data);}               
    );
```

My PHP script file (mytest.php):

```
<?php
    echo "PHP a= " , $_GET["a"], " b= ", $_GET["b"];
?>
```

I have tried `.post` and `.get` as well, but without success.

All I get is **"PHP a=  b= "**
I have checked with wireshark, and the parameters are transmitted with the `.post` call, so why can I not see/access them in the php script?

Comment: Isn't it `echo "PHP a= " . $_GET["a"] . " b= " . $_GET["b"];`?

Comment: OP, add this to mytest.php: 
echo "<pre>";
ob_start();
var_dump('$_GET',$_GET,'$_POST',$_POST,'$_COOKIE',$_COOKIE,'$_FILES',$_FILES);
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean(),ENT_SUBSTITUTE).'</pre>';

Comment: Yes, thank you. I thought .load is using GET but it is actually using POST. With $_POST it works.

From the JQuery .load documentation: "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed." I should have seen that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are posting the variables. But you are referencing GET.

Change

```
echo "PHP a= " , $_GET["a"], " b= ", $_GET["b"];
```

to

```
echo "PHP a= " , $_POST["a"], " b= ", $_POST["b"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your parameters are submitted by post, you have to access them in the $_POST array.

```
<?php
  echo "PHP a= " , $_POST["a"], " b= ", $_GET["b"];
?>
```

Regards
Sascha

Comment: you forgot the second _GET